# Insert obj to array without any animation or movement

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a horizontal scrollbar in Angular - when a new event is coming I insert a new object to the list and then the list is making some animation to make a move left/right.

Also, I have a button to stop the animation and leave the view on the active object and do not move to the new obj, 
its works and the animation stopped but there is still affects on the push/unshift event and the event is moving a bit to the left

the code after the angular detect there is a new event comming :
stoppedBtn = false means that now there is animation

```
scope.list.unshift(newobj); // this makes the little movment
if(scope.stoppedBtn === false){
    $timeout(function () {
        $('#sliderDiv_' + newobj.id + ' img').css('opacity', 0);
        $(".loader").css('display', 'block');
        $('#slidediv' + newobj.id).hide();
        $('#slidediv_' + newobj.id).animate({width:'toggle'}, 500, 'swing',
        function() {
          $('#sliderDiv_' + newobj.id + ' img').animate({opacity: 1});
        });
    },10);
}
```

so it is not enter to the `if` statement , but still suffered from the unshift regular movement

Comment: I think you need save old scroll position and set it after adding obj

Comment: if I will do that i will not see any jumps? 

and what is the best way to do that

thanks @MaximShoustin